# kendo.ui.progress($("#treeid"), true); not working when select the node in kendoui treeview

Tags: jquery, checkbox, treeview, kendo-ui

KendoUI tree-view is synchronized with KendoUI multi-select, so when I select the node in tree-view control goes to select same item in multi-select. So I have a function in that function I put `kendo.ui.progress($("#treeid"), true);` and after this script for select the same item in multi-select.
this is simple try:

```
console.log('in ondata');
                var id = $(this).attr('id_a');
                if (typeof combined != 'undefined') {
                    var selTag = $("input[type='hidden'][id='" + id + "']").attr('selId');
                    var classId = $("input[type='hidden'][id='" + id + "']").attr('classid');
                    console.log(classId);
                    kendo.ui.progress($("#"+classId), true);
                    console.log('after progress start...');

                }
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                        console.log('in ckecked..');
                        $("input[type='checkbox'][name='c_" + id + "']").closest("div").find("span:last").addClass("k-state-selected");
                        if (typeof combined != 'undefined') {
                            addToMs(classId, selTag, id);
                        }
                    } else {
                                console.log('in ckecked else..');
                                $("input[type='checkbox'][name='c_" + id + "']").closest(
                                "div").find("span:last").removeClass(
                                "k-state-selected");
                                if (typeof combined != 'undefined') {
                                removeMs(classId, selTag, id);
                                }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Please, try to re-arrange your code, make some edit to improve readability. If you'd like to get some help, try to make your question as clear as possible.

Comment: @RadimKöhler: I have js file which contains two main functions 1. kendouiTree() and 2. kendouiMultiSelect().
So when I select item using multiSelect, the tree is expanded and select the same item and same when I check the node in tree it selects same Item in multiSelect at this selection time I want to put progressbar but It's not working properly. I am using above function to select same item in multiSelect.

                                          Thanks & Regards,
                                           Vijay G. Vyas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use
http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#dialog

this instead of 

kendo.ui.progress($(“#treeid”), true);

Comment: It is working, So the issue is kendo.ui.progress($(“#treeid”), true); Method.

                                                 Thanks